# Record calls using accessibility service android 10

Tags: android, kotlin, accessibility, call-recording

**can someone please guide me on how to record audio using an accessibility service any help would be greatly appreciated.** 
manifests.xml declaration

```
<service
            android:name=".services.call.StartAccessibilityService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
                android:resource="@xml/start_accessibility_service" />
        </service>
```

kotlin code

```
 class StartAccessibilityService : AccessibilityService() {
        override fun onAccessibilityEvent(accessibilityEvent: AccessibilityEvent) {
            if (accessibilityEvent.eventType == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED) {
                Log.d(TAG, "accessibilityEvent " +accessibilityEvent.eventType)
    
                val instance = RecordingApplication.getInstance()
    
                if (instance != null && !RecordingApplication.isServiceStarted()) {
                    RecordingApplication.getCallLog()?.let {
                        RecordingJobService.startRecording(instance, it)
                        RecordingApplication.setServiceStarted(true)
    
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
        override fun onInterrupt() {}
    
        companion object {
            val TAG = StartAccessibilityService::class.java.name
        }
    }
```

xml/start_accessibility_service

```
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeNotificationStateChanged"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackSpoken|feedbackHaptic|feedbackAudible|feedbackVisual|feedbackGeneric|feedbackAllMask"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault"
    android:description="@string/acces_serv_description"
    />
```

Comment: What's the issue you're having and what's the tutorial you are trying to follow?

Comment: the audio is completely silent.but according to google docs i should be able to use it if it is a accessibility service .

Comment: Where you able to solve the issue? Is your recorder working?